# WebApi HTTPPOST Endpoint not being hit

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following simple HTTPPOST endpoint;

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("forgotPassword")]
public IHttpActionResult ForgotPassword(string userName, string callbackUrl)
```

Where the controller is decorated as follows;

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/accounts")]
public class AccountsController : ApiController
```

Now when i try to test this endpoint in postman, using the following url;

> http://localhost:11217/api/accounts/forgotPassword

with the strings in the body of the message

I get the following return.

> {   "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request
>   URI 'http://localhost:11217/api/accounts/forgotPassword'.",
>   "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Accounts'
>   that matches the request." }

Now I would rather not have to create a model for the two strings (if possible). Also if I try to put the params in the query string I get a potantially dangerous request response

> http://localhost:11217/api/accounts/forgotPassword/test&callbackUrl=local

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send mulitple parameters when doing a post request you should create a DTO that contains the parameters as

```
public class forgetPasswordDTO
{
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string callbackUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Then add the DTO as a method parameter with the [FromBody]

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("forgotPassword")]
public IHttpActionResult ForgotPassword([FromBody] forgetPasswordDTO data)
```

And in you client, create the object as

```
var data = {
    'userName': user,
    'callbackUrl': url
};
```

And add it to the body of the request.

[Here's](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods) a nice article about this topic

Comment: I thought so, I just hoped the binder would be able to get around this.

Comment: `[FromBody]` should only be necessary for simple types (e.g. string). For a DTO object in a POST request the binder should try and read it from the request body automatically. See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, did not know that.