# Require Json String to call Multiple Parameters of type string list in web api mvc

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I having a WebApi in my controller something like so how can i pass a json data of array in this method :

```
[HttpPost]
public List<string> Data([FromBody]List<string> data, [FromBody]List<string> tmp)
{
    return data;
}
```

So, my question is how can a call the method from post man software i need to call this method at android side also that's why

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082163/webapi-httppost-endpoint-not-being-hit/40082757#40082757

Comment: Please post example json.

Comment: So, you want to json string for testing purpose?

Comment: yeah but i cant access this method in my .net because i need to use same method in android side also so

Comment: *my .net because i need to use same method in android* What does it mean?

Comment: Now complete scenario in my mind, you're an android developer and some .NET developer developed API for you. if so, then I think you have to ask to .NET developer who developed this WebApi for you. How they tested it before gave to you? And even does it worked? as per as i know, I can tell this is not directly possible using a POST operation with WebAPI. Does it make sense?

Comment: i mean i can't access this method from postman while passing a json data so is there any solution to pass data from postman.

Comment: Its not clear what you want. Do you want an example on how to call this method using Postman? Or the code to call it in java? Be more specific.