# ASP.NET WebAPI and Angular POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI controller

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public SomeResult MyAction(string name, string message)
    {
        return SomeResult.???;
    }
}
```

I have an angular controller calling this method

```
$http
    .post("/api/My/MyAction", { name: "bob", message: "hello" })
    .then(function(xhr) { ... }, function(xhr) { ... });
```

I get this result

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.

What did I do wrong?

P.S. It's not the URL...It works when I use `HttpGet` and append the parameters to the query string.

Comment: Please post your routing configuration calls.

Comment: Check answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082163/webapi-httppost-endpoint-not-being-hit/40082757#40082757

Comment: It might just be a typo, but in your sample, the action name is "MyAction" but the URL you're using in angular is "MyAccount". Also, as the first commenter said, it would be useful to see the routing config.

Comment: change `/api/MyController/MyAccount` to `/api/My/MyAccount`

Comment: @ADyson okay, confusing as it is...it's NOT the url!

Comment: @Daniel okay, confusing as it is...it's NOT the url!

Comment: Use these parameters in uri for POST. Or pack them in class and mark as [FromBody]

Comment: Use Fiddler and check what actually gets sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more than one attribute for post requests, you can use [FromBody] in your controller and make a ViewModel class. Example:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage UpdateNumber([FromBody]UpdateNumberViewModel model)
        {
           //To do business
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

UpdateViewModel:

```
public class UpdateViewModel
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Title{ get; set; }

    }
```

Angular:

```
var model = {                    
                    Id: 1,
                    Title: 'Vai filhão'
                }

    $http.post('/api/controller/updateNumber/',model).then(function () { alert("OK"); }, function () {alert("something wrong"); });
```

You can see more details about how web api it works here: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: similar to another answer on here, `[FromBody]` should not be necessary for a complex type such as this. It's only required when you try to pass a simple type (e.g. string) in the body. See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Exactly. i'll edit my answer...

Answer (score 2):

I've faced that problem, if you google there are different ways to solve it. One of the easiest requires to use only one input object in you WebApi controller, so in you case just crate a class

```
public class InputData {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your input to the new create object with `[FromBody]` prefix (maybe not mandatory, see @ADyson comment)

```
public SomeResult MyAction([FromBody]InputData inputData)
```

Comment: `[FromBody]` should not be necessary for a complex type such as this. It's only required when you try to pass a simple type (e.g. string) in the body. See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: @ADyson thank you for the suggestion, from your link it seems reasonable that it's not mandatory